# How to determine which button was tapped?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4

I have this calendar, made up of 48 frames created programatically... when I do a UITapGestureRecognizer, it returns x,y coordinates for the frame... any idea how to determine which frame was tapped?

UPDATE:  this is the code to create the frame:

```
self.frame = frame;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:rd1 green:gr1 blue:bl1 alpha:1.0]; 
[[self layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]]; 
[[self layer] setBorderWidth:0.5];  
[[self layer] setCornerRadius:10]; 
[self setClipsToBounds: YES];
```

Comment: Could you provide more info, e.g. how do you create and layout your 48 buttons? For example you can iterate through all buttons and test if your coordinates belong to button's frame or calculate button from coordinates if you know the layout rule...

Comment: And if you have buttons anyway, why not assign an action to each button rather than have gesture recognizer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing - then the routine below might be of use. It gets the touch coordinates and then tests it against each rect in an array. It the CPPoint is inside a rect then you have your index number and based on that you can do what you need to do.

Depending on how you define your array of rects, you may need to normalize the touch CGPoint.

Anyway - hope it helps.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 

// See if the point touched is within these rectangular bounds
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.gridRect, point))
{
    CGRect rect;
    int cnt = self.cellRectArray.count;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {

        rect = [[self.cellRectArray objectAtIndex:i] cellRect];
        rect = CGRectOffset(rect, self.gridOriginX, self.gridOriginY);
        rect = CGRectInset(rect, 10, 10);
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)) {
            // do something
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think this will do it... I think I need to start out by capturing the coordinates of each rectangle and storing them in an array, along with other data, like date, etc.  I'll give it a try and get back to you... thank you for responding!

Comment: the only tricky thing is @ working in the same coordinate space: touch coordinate vs UIView coordinates. That is what the `CGRectOffset` is for - to shift them relative to the x/y of the view. Also "cellRect" is a custom NSObject based class for storing the CGRects in an NSArray since you can't store raw CGRects in an NSArray. - Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if you have buttons, if you enable them, tapping on them will trigger the method you linked to the tapping action.

Thus each button has a "tag" property.

the tag property can let you know which button triggered the method.

edit :

if your button belongs to UIButton class, you can get the button's tag through the tag property, ie :

```
mybutton.tag
```

or

```
[mybutton tag]
```

Comment: your code doesn't create UIButton in the meaning of UIButton class. see : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Comment: I understand what you're saying... ok, so let's change it.. I am drawing a rectangle... how can I identify each one (like the "tag" in a UIButton)?

Comment: myButton.tag = 1 , myOtherButton.tag = 2 , etc. Then make a method to link their action to. take a look at sample codes given in the link i posted in my previous comment. You'll see how to manage to work with UIButton

Comment: I don't want to work with UIButton... I want to work with the rectangle as I have drawn them...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` then why not just ask which view it is attached to?

```
- (void)cellTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer;
{
    NSLog(@"%@", tapGestureRecognizer.view);
}
```